# Why are phrase structure rules always inconsistent?

Tags: syntax, grammar, phrase-structure

I've noticed that phrase structure rules have been very inconsistent over my studies. I've seen NP = (det)(adj)N ; NP = (det)N(PP); these definitions seem to change with context. Is it just because there's no strict phrase formalisms in language? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it's because there are many possible phrase structures. Typically there are dozens of "NP =" and "VP =" rules in any PS grammar that attempts to cover more than a toy language.

Comment: Then why make phrase structure rules in the first place? I understand trying to represent the relationship between constituencies in trees, but phrase structure rules seem rather frivolous.

Comment: @Farting, yes, PS rules in the traditional form are rather silly. The number of those rules that you would need to start to cover the combinatorial properties of just a few lexical items is enormous. A better approach is to focus on the actual lexical items and how they combine with other lexical items.

Comment: The reason why they're presenting them to you is that they're baby steps toward syntactic rules: Start with an input and change it somehow in a deterministic fashion to produce an output. It's just an instructional strategy, and probly not a very good one.

Comment: I am having second thoughts about the meaning of your question. Are you concerned with the fact that there are several PS rules NP= ... in the same PS grammar for English, or with the fact that these rules are not always the same, depending on the book, the chapter, the exercise or the teacher ? My answer assumed the latter.

Comment: @babou both of them really. But I think you answered my question well. I've seen multiple definitions for something like "NP=..." within a textbook/course, while at the same time seen varying PS definitions for the same given language across different textbooks/courses. Because of this, I didn't know if the courses/textbooks I've experienced were incorporating different syntactic theories for their PS rules, or if PS rules are more or less inconsistent.

Comment: @RECURSIVEFARTS I don't think it's right to describe PS-rules as 'inconsistent' just because they have multiple rules with the same left-hand side. What do you mean by inconsistent exactly? PS-grammars work that way by design - it's necessary, e.g. to capture the possibility of recursively adjoining adjectives to nouns. You need (at least) the following 2 rules: *NP -> car* and *NP -> Adj NP*. I don't see any inconsistencies here, the idea that PS-rules should be uniquely specified by their left-hand side is a stipulation.

Comment: @PElliott the fact that PS rules seem to change to fit to a specific context/view of interpreting a language is why I felt that they were inconsistent. But you're right, maybe 'inconsistent' is the wrong word. Before asking this question I saw PS rules as a prescriptive tool (WHOOPS), which lead me to this confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to describe a given language, even in a given
formalism. I would think that at any time, a language is always
inconsistent. Diachronic evolution seems a good reason to believe
that. Latin has slowly evolved into Italian, Spanish, Catalan,
Roumanian, Portuguese and French (what did I forget?). Actually there
have been many more dialects and variants that did not all
survive. And the evolution has been progressive. How can you expect to
have consistency in such an unstable context?

I do not know of such experiments, but I would guess that no two
people will agree everywhere on the grammaticality of some sets of
sentences.

But that shows most for the visible (surface) syntax of languages. One
task of linguistics is to identify deeper and more stable concepts
that structure the language in a more consistent way.

What matters for surface syntax, that you are considering, is more to
understand adequate and tractable formalisms that will let you
describe the language (almost) adequately, and develop techniques to
attain from that the deeper structure. Distinct surface descriptions in
the chosen formalism can hopefully give you similar understanding.

Actually, even the choice of the formalism can be open, and there are
many competing. Even if you consider only phrase structure, the
variant you have been using seem to be the context-free variant of
Chomsky.  But others, with interesting descriptive properties have
been developped, such as tree-adjoining-grammars, to give an
example. Then these formalisms can form a skeleton to be completed by
more detailed information (features).

Also relations with the lexicon have to be established, and structural
information and features can be attached to the lexicon.
Interestingly, when choosing or designing a formalism, independently
of the language to be described, there will be tension between the
"phrase structure skeleton" and the lexicon, regarding where some of
the structural information should be placed. Emphasizing the lexicon
can also be done by lexicalizing the phrase structure skeleton (which
is what Greibach normal form does for context-free languages).

And there are other very different kinds of formalisms, such as
categorial grammars.

What matters is to acquire the knowledge, understanding and effective
usage of natural language description tools. Then you use these tools
to give the best description you can of the natural language
structure. We do not all have to agree on what might be the best
description of the structure of a natural language (hence the
variations you complain about), but we need common descriptive tools
to understand each other when discussing these issues.  The formalisms
are (part of) the language needed by linguists to exchange and discuss
meaningfully about the natural language.

Comment: The answer provides way more information than the question required. My guess is that Farting has no idea what most of this answer is talking about.

Comment: Though it's pretty much all useful information, and -- who knows? -- somebody else might read it, too. Or chance upon it while doing a search for several of the terms. We're not really dealing with individual requests here in principle; we're making informative texts. The variety of questioners and their wildly diverse presuppositions as shown on ELU means that there's almost always a mismatch between what the questioner is asking and the information they actually need, whether they requested it or not.

Comment: @Jlawler, the question asks about "phrase structure rules". Nowhere in the answer is the term "phrase structure rules" or "PS rules" even used. In short, the answer misses the target almost entirely.

Comment: Though the reply was a bit advanced, I think it helped answer my question. I was seeing PS rules as more of a strict generative rule, rather than a descriptive tool.